# ComboBox selectedValue/Item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to do this edit page where when a user wants to edit a case, it get the case id and brings the user to another form where the user can edit information only for selected case id.
One of the informations is called agents, where a agent is already selected. For example this case id =20 contains a agent information that has agent20. In the this edit page, i'm trying a combobox where agent20 is already selected as a default value in the combobox when on page_onload but the combobox already contains the rest of the agent like agent 1 to 20. Please note that this is a windows form and not a asp.net as asp.net can use the code of  FindByValue....

```
        SqlDataAdapter ad4 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
        ds4.Clear();
        SqlConnection connection4 = new SqlConnection();

        String sqlText4 = "SELECT * FROM [Agent] WHERE TypeID = 1";
        connection4.ConnectionString = "-connectionstring-";
        command4.Connection = connection4;
        command4.CommandText = sqlText4;
        ad4.SelectCommand = command4;
        connection4.Open();
        ad4.Fill(ds4, "data");
        connection4.Close();

        comboBox1.DataSource = ds4.Tables["data"];
        //comboBox1.SelectionStart = agentnumber;
        //comboBox1.GetItemText(agentnumber);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "AgentName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "AgentID";
```

Comment: what is your actual requirement,you want to pass the value,or you want to set the combo with the particular value,AND guys please dont downvote simply,give him chance to clear himself

Answer (score 0):

don't understand what you need but I try to give you some hints:

to set a value in a combobox:

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue = myNewId
```

to retrieve the selected value of a combobox:

```
myNewId = comboBox1.SelectedValue
```

the `SelectedIndex` property behave like `SelectedValue` but it set/returns the index of the selected item, for example if the selected item is the third of the list, it returns 3.

the `Text` property set/returns simply the text of the selected item (in your case something like "Agent20").

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) you have a complete overview of the ComboBox class.

Hope this helps to start investigating further.